# Easily generate SQL script for an Array of objects - Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, postgresql

I made a Rake Task to parse information from some websites (using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) gem) and save everything to a .json file. To do this, I store all objects inside and array and before the rake task ends, I call a method to serialize the array of objects to an JSON file.

**Currently, I'm doing something like:**

```
# Declaring a global variable inside the 'namespace'
@all_objects = []

# Each website I want parse is added to '@all_objects' array
this_object = Object.new(:attr1 => variable1, :attr2 => variable2)
@all_objects << this_object

# After run the code above for all websites, I save them in .json file
File.open("public/data.json", "w") { 
    |f| f.write(@all_objects.to_json)
}
```

### **My question is:**

What is the easist way to do the same thing, but serializing to an insert SQL script? Exist some method like `myArray.to_postgresql` or `myArray.to_mysql`, that get all objects of this array and generate a script to insert this data in a SQL database(INSERT into...)?

Since now, thanks!

Comment: SQL scripts are not intended for serialization at all. Unless you need to insert your data in a database. Is this the case?

Comment: I want convert my Array of objects into different scripts and JSON. I have this array of objects and I want publish them, so anyone can download it and insert this data into their databases. For easily import this data, I think in JSON and SQL scripts that insert things on database. Have another way or am I right - this is the best way to publish and share my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After search a lot over the Internet and forums, I found "models_to_sql" gem, from [Martin Provencher](https://github.com/vivrass).

But this gem only works for Rails 3.2 and older, and my application uses Rails 4.0. I [talked with author](https://github.com/vivrass/models-to-sql/issues/1) and he doesn't want support this gem anymore. So I discovered by myself how to support Rails 4.0 and now I'm maintaining this gem.

#### Download the ["models-to-sql-rails" gem here](https://github.com/paladini/models-to-sql-rails), supporting Rails 4.0 and older.

---

With this gem, you can easily do the following. (the examples inside *values* are just a joke, you will get the correct values when using it in your object).

For objects:

```
object.to_sql_insert
# INSERT INTO modelName (field1, field2) VALUES ('Wow, amaze gem', 'much doge')
```

For array of objets:

```
array_of_objects.to_sql_insert
# INSERT INTO modelName (field1, field2) VALUES ('Awesome doge', "im fucking cop")
# INSERT INTO modelName (field1, field2) VALUES ('much profit', 'much doge')
# (...)
```

Just see the [Github of this project](https://github.com/paladini/models-to-sql-rails) and you'll find how to install and use this wonderful gem.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:

1. Run your query for example;

`Model.last`

1. Copy SQL statement output from Rails console.
2. Open Sequel Pro and paste SQL statement and run query.

Now you can simple 'Copy as SQL insert' from Sequel Pro.